# Looking for files ONLY in subdirectory

Tags: shell-script, grep

So let's say I want to search for files that are C files. How do I go about searching for them ONLY in my sub-directories?

I tried: `ls -R | egrep .c$`, but that also searches for `.c` files in my current directory as well. How do I filter out the files in my current directory and only care about the ones in my sub-directory?

Answer (score 4):

Strictly in subdirectories,

```
ls */*.c
```

Recursively in subdirectories of subdirectories,

```
find */ -type f -name '*.c' -print
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use file globbing (i.e. asterisk expansion) with `find` like triplee says, of course, but...that command made me wince.

When you're using the `find` command, it has so many built-in flags you can use to tell it explicitly what you want it to do, that there's no good reason to use `ls` with file globbing.  And there are plenty of reasons *not* to.  For instance, **file globbing will generally ignore any hidden files or directories.**  This means that any files whose name begins with a dot, or which reside in directories (or subdirectories of directories) whose name begins with a dot, *will be ignored*.  Maybe that's what you want, but with file globbing it's not easily and directly in your control; with `find` it is.

Find is the correct tool for the job.  The option you want is `-mindepth`.  Use it like this:

`find . -mindepth 2 -type f -iname '*.c'`

This finds all files (non-directories, non-special files) that are within a directory within the current directory, or any number of levels further down, whose name ends in `.c` or `.C`.  (The `-iname` flag means to ignore case.)

(Note that this will not follow symbolic links; that's usually how you want it anyway but you can check `man find` to learn how to adjust this behavior.)

As a sidenote, I also used `ls` piped to `grep` for quite some time before learning the `find` command, but `find` is really the better method.  I found the practical commands given at this link to be very helpful in actually starting to *use* `find` in day to day work: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-linux-find-command-examples/

Comment: Not sure how `-mindepth 2` is better than explicitly listing the target directories.  It is certainly less portable, which may or may not be a concern for the OP, but also makes the answer less readily reusable by others.  If you want to include dotfiles in the glob, that's `.[!.]*/`

Answer (score 0):

You can you -depth +1 to remove searching the current folder.

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -depth +1 -print
```